efivarfs size grows every reboot
I have a dual boot system, windows and Ubuntu.
I noticed from yesterday, that every time i boot after power-off, the efivarfs increases in about 1kb or a bit less.
here is my df -h :
tmpfs           3.2G   11M  3.1G   1% /run

/dev/nvme0n1p6   46G   17G   27G  40% /

tmpfs            16G  258M   16G   2% /dev/shm

tmpfs           5.0M   12K  5.0M   1% /run/lock

**efivarfs        268K  195K   69K  74% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars**

/dev/nvme0n1p1  256M   44M  213M  18% /boot/efi

/dev/nvme0n1p7  117G  5.4G  106G   5% /home

tmpfs           3.2G  132K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000

it was around 67% and from me rebooting to try and fix the problem, it got to 74%.
I believe this is a problem is'nt it? what if it gets to 100%?
can anyone please help me fix it and maybe explain what is happening here?
I dont have secure boot on, no fast startup, no fwupdmgr updates and no pstore logs.
Thank you anyone who will help.

It is not a problem.
Mine is currently at 78%
/sys/firmware is not a “real” filesystem, it is part of a RAM-based filesystem called sysfs . The sysfs filesystem provides information about devices and drivers in the kernel through virtual files, so certain device properties can be interacted with using “normal” file operations.
Since sysfs resides in memory, it is kind of a temporary structure that gets recreated fresh at every boot. There is no need to make it larger than whatever virtual files it needs to contain, so usually it appears to be full or nearly full.
NVRAM and EFI boot variables are not related to the sysfs virtual filesystem.
https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/efivars-is-full-is-this-a-problem/34616
Note: When looking at the results of df (disk free) you should concentrate on the used space and not the percentage as the to total size can change between boots.
Although a full efivarfs is unlikely to cause problems and if it occurs it should be fixed with a re-boot there may still be a problem if the BIOS NVRAM, itself gets full. BIOS, NVRAM size vary across motherboards together with different storage methods makes this very difficult to predict. It is also outside the scope of this group.
It is possible to manage some of the efivarfs which in turn will update the NVRAM using efibootmgr. efibootmgr is a userspace application used to modify the UEFI Boot Manager. This application can create and destroy boot entries, change the boot order, change the next running boot option, and more. You can, for example, remove duplicate boot options with efibootmgr -D It is a good idea to remove old, unused entries.

Thank you. Are you sure about that? I came across the link you sent, but i also came across places where they said reaching 100% might cause issues. So you are saying its ok if it reaches 100% and that it is increasing a bit every reboot? This is self managed by the system?

I have added more details and even some ways to mange the efi variables. I hope that answers you question.
